# A question about dependence in a doubly nested loop

Tags: loops, parallel-processing, nested

I read an example from the paper **Wolf M.E and Lam M.S, A Loop Transformation Theory and an Algorithm to Maximize Parallelism, IEEE Transactions on Parallel and Distributed Systems, Vol 2. No 4, pp. 452-471, 1991** regarding loop transformations as a required step for loop parallelization, that uses a double loop in the form

```
DO I = 0 TO 5 
   DO J = 0 TO 6
         A(J+1)=(1/3)[A(J)+A(J+1)+A(J+2)]
   ENDDO
ENDDO
```

According to the authors this loop has three distance vector namely d1=(0,1), d2=(1,0) and d3=(1,-1).

A have a question regarding this situation:

Since the loop statement uses only the "J" counter what is the meaning of using the outer loop and how these distance vectors are computed since the "I" counter is missing from the statement?

Thanks a lot

This is a theoretical question about a situation i do not understand.

Comment: The inner loop change the array in-place so each iteration of the `i`-based loop is not the same. Since the operation is a kind of stencil, the operation is a bit similar to applying N times a basic blur which results in a kind of Gaussian blur with a rather large radius (but it is a slow implementation of that). In practice, writing in the input make things a bit more complex.